# When SE unilaterally alters an author's name to "user123xxx", isn't it breaching its licence?

Tags: discussion, legal, licensing, attribution, creative-commons

A user recently left English.SE in dissatisfaction with other users' behaviour, and he asked SE to delete both his English.SE account and all of the work he had posted to that subsite. But while SE deleted his account, it has continued to distribute his work, now attributed not to the original author handle but to a generic author name of its choosing, namely "user" followed by a string of digits.

I am told that the following sequence of events is "normal" here and has happened with thousands of pieces of work:

- an angry user quits, asking for his account to be deleted
- the user conveys a wish for SE to stop using the work he has contributed, and he may himself try to delete it or replace it with "deleted" notices
- SE deletes his account, but it continues to distribute the work, attributed to a new author name that it creates for the purpose.

Surely this usage is a breach of the licence that SE receives when a user accepts the [terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal), namely the [Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike licence](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode)? That licence states:

> "[4c] If you Distribute [...] the Work [...], You must provide [...] the name of the Original Author (or pseudonym, if applicable) if supplied"

Comment: Sure, we keep his name with his post. Up until the point he wishes to no longer be associated with us.

Comment: You conveniently left out the "unless a request has been made pursuant to Section 4(a)" part of that sentence.

Comment: But "*please delete my account*" and "*please stop distributing my work*" don't add up to "*I am granting you a dispensation from your obligation to attribute my work to me if you continue to distribute it*".

Comment: @animuson - 4a refers to collections from which the licensor has given notice that he wishes credit to himself for a component work (as required under 4c) to be removed. It's not relevant here.

Comment: You should also bold the last two words of that sentence: **if supplied**. Deleting their profile removes their name from our system. So their name is no longer supplied anymore, and cannot be provided as attribution. But in the grand scheme, a deletion request is inherently a disassociation request. What's irrelevant here is the user's desire for us to stop distributing content - that has no bearing on anything.

Comment: @animuson - The company is responsible for its system. "Delete account" means delete subscriber rights, not delete licensor rights. A licensee should keep hold of the name of the licensor, so as to be able to comply with its obligation to attribute. Sure, the company does not have to stop distributing content, but the receipt of a request to do so should make it clear that the author isn't saying "*please remove my name from it, but distribute it under a made-up name instead*".

Comment: @ruffle We do explicitly mention exactly what will happen to any user over 1,000 reputation, as there is no automated system they can use that will delete their profile without requiring them to *talk to us* first. I can get you a copy of the standard email we send if you want to see it. Some users do opt to cancel deletion because they'd rather not lose their attribution - and that's completely up to them.

Comment: But in most cases, even if we kept their display name at the time of deletion, it wouldn't be useful. Display names are not unique, and stating it was answered by "Tim" doesn't provide any more attribution than stating it was answered by "user123456" - a plain name that doesn't link to an actual person provides no more attribution than an ID number.

Comment: The [help center states](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) *"User deletion is irreversible! By sending this request, your votes will be revoked, and all of your content will be made anonymous."* (Well, more anonymous than it already was.) If you go through with this, you should be aware of the repercussions. Note also that "Original Author" (according to [the current license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)) can refer to the publisher, if the writer cannot be identified. I would bet that the publisher here is Stack Exchange (But I'm no lawyer).

Comment: @animuson - Thanks - I'd be interested to see it. Without having read it yet, I agree that the company is within its rights to say "*It's up to us whether or not to delete your subscriber account, and we will only delete it if you grant us an alteration to the licence so that we can continue to distribute your work without attributing it to you.*" But if "Tim" is the name the user supplies, then that's the "original author" name, whether unique or not.

Comment: @HDE226868 - The "*by sending this request, [...] all of your content will be made anonymous*" bit is interesting, but is it a request for permission or is it a statement that the licensee will act in a way that it may not have the right to? (I don't know the answer to that question, btw!)

Answer (score 22):

We do not conduct "partial" deletions here - a deletion is full and removes all traces of "you" as a person from our system, which includes your display name, because that's exactly how deletion is *supposed* to work. Deletion is meant for users who do not want any identifying details about them on our site anymore. Thus, a request to have your profile deleted is inherently a request to disassociate all of your posts as well, **and we tell users that when they try to delete their profile**.

[image: How to delete your account]

Further, if you have at least 1,000 reputation on the site, the automated system will kick you out and require one of us to look at the request and verify that you really want to delete your profile. We send a standard email which does a few things:

- Asks for the specific instance that caused this, in case we can resolve the issue.
- Clarifies the implications of deleting your profile **again**.
- Gives you instructions on how to proceed.

> I'm sorry to hear that you wish to have your profile deleted. May I ask if there was a specific incident that led to this decision? Is there anything we can help resolve?
>
> I also want to take a moment to clarify the implications of profile deletion. Deletion is pretty much irreversible, and you will have no way to regain any of your original content, should this deletion be carried out and you change your mind later on. Your questions and answers will remain on the site, but will be disassociated and anonymized (the author will be listed as "usernnnnn") and will not indicate your authorship even if you later return to the site.
>
> If you are sure you would like your profile to be deleted, I will just need to verify your ownership of it. To do this, please [edit your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current) and modify the 'About Me' section to contain the words 'delete me', then send us a link to the profile to verify your request.
>
> Please let us know how you'd like to proceed or if there are any concerns we can address before you make this decision.

Those users who are truly against losing their association to the content they've created will opt out of deletion at this point and do the more logical thing - just stop using the site. Because, again, deletion is for *removing every detail about you*, and not for quitting but still somehow keeping everything you posted connected to you anyways.

But even if the user *does* go through with the deletion, we still **try to maintain some semblance of attribution** by using the user's ID number in the display name. Since the display name is no longer provided, we have to revert to alternate means, and the user ID is a unique value that can still identify that "someone who had this ID number but is no longer on our site is the person who posted this." This is quite different than a normal disassociation request where we would manually remove a user's name from a post, which leaves the name on the post simply as "anon" with absolutely *no* information about who the author might have been.

Comment: So the company has the right to distribute its licensor's work without attributing it to the original author - a right additional to those the licensor gave it - because it makes getting that additional right a condition of deleting a subscriber account? I don't think that stands up. Subscriber rights are not *rights*, in the sense of rights given by contract in exchange for some benefits - they are just what the company lets individuals do on its website and can stop letting them do when it chooses.

Comment: What happens to attribution when the company deletes an account without a user asking it to? Is account deletion any different from the termination of a subscriber’s right to use the company's services, to use the language of section 3 of the ToS? And what happens if the ex-subscriber notifies the company after requesting deletion that if the company insists on distributing his work he wants to be attributed under the original name he gave? The word "irrevocable" doesn't appear in the "How to delete your account" text you quote.

Comment: Just to gloss that second comment: say someone wishes to leave but doesn't wish to grant a right to distribute without attribution. Would it be in his interests, instead of politely requesting subscriber account deletion, to start saying obscene stuff or posting spam, in order to provoke a without-request deletion? Because in those circumstances, I don't think anyone has argued that a right to distribute without attribution would be created.

Comment: @ruffle That behavior would result in a suspension, not a deletion. We rarely *ever* forcibly delete user accounts with valuable content (stuff that couldn't just be deleted).

Comment: OK, thanks. That clarifies to some extent.

Answer (score 2):

If a user asks to get his account deleted and thus his posts to be unassociated, there is nothing unilateral here. The rights to publish the posts are granted to SE, so they are free to keep the posts and distribute them under the license at time of writing.

Comment: Can you argue in favour of the "thus"? When a user specifically asks SE to delete his account and to stop distributing his work, why does that amount to letting the licensee off from its obligation, if it distributes his work, to attribute it to him? The author's name can be attributed to the work without the company running an account in that name. If the company's software won't allow that, it could get it fixed.

Comment: You agree to SE to distribute your code under a certain license. If you delete your account, there is no more attribution to do than pointing to the source you got it from. Still attributed, but not with the previous display name of the user.

Comment: The licence says the work, if distributed, must be attributed to the name of the original author or pseudonym - and pseudonym means one supplied by the author, which is more than a "display name" that happens to be used by the company's system. Sending the company that name from your keyboard is an act of saying "this is the name you must attribute my work to". Why does "please delete my subscriber account" negate that?

Comment: It is also a disassociation request so all work contributed by you will not be attributed to you any more. Period.

Comment: If you attribute, you attribute to a user profile, since the name is not unique. Profile deleted = no association = no attribution.

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, the user's original name is still preserved for posterity in the Web Archive and Google Cache - and can be found by simple correlation of the live and archived versions of the same question.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - It's not "period". It doesn't say it's a dissociation request. Why do you think it implies one? Or to be more exact, why do you think it implies a *grant of permission by the licensor* to distribute without attribution to the original author under the name the author supplied?

Comment: What part of *all of your content will be made anonymous* is ambiguous? Nothing will be pointing back at you any more.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - The issue isn't the meaning of those words; it's their legal implication in context. (And anyway they are not strictly true, because the post-deletion attribution isn't "anonymous". So one could answer that an ambiguous part of that sentence is the word "anonymous" - does it mean *without the original author's name* or *without any name*? But that's by the by.)

Comment: This argument wouldn't hold up anywhere else and it shouldn't hold up here. Disney decides to stop posting content on youtube. Youtube keeps all the existing content up but just changes the name of the channel to User135344. The only thing keeping this working is that no one has yet sued Stack Exchange for breach of licensing terms.