# How is removing the user's name from their post compatible with copyright?

Tags: support, copyright, attribution

So it was explained to me that if a user is removed, regardless of the Stack Exchange site, the name will also be removed from all of their posts. It is completely unimportant at this point why the user was removed, it shouldn't be discussed here as it is completely off-topic.

No matter what the reason may be, it is clearly a copyright violation since Stack Exchange appropriates the user's intellectual property (the post). Since this procedure is present on all Stack Exchange sites, it cannot be discussed on any of these sites. I have also read the terms of service several times, but there is nothing there about me giving up all my rights to my posts to Stack Exchange.

The question only applies to the case if the user was involuntarily removed. [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277440/when-se-unilaterally-alters-an-authors-name-to-user123xxx-isnt-it-breaching) probably refers to the case when the user voluntarily removes their account.

To explain what I actually mean by the question, I have an example here. Let's say there is content from userA, which is under the usual license on stackexchange. This content is published by someone else but under the name author userB. The publication itself is of course not a copyright violation, as it should be under license, but the fact that userB is listed as the author is such a violation.

Comment: Read [this](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/). You'll find there "The licensor cannot revoke these freedoms as long as you follow the license terms", and also [here](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/License_Versions#Detailed_attribution_comparison_chart), it clearly says "Creator **if supplied**". Bottom line, there's no requirement to have the name. The content belongs to Stack Exchange once submitted.

Comment: Is this about self-deletions or deletions by moderators? If the former, you're told what will happen. If the latter, then most of the content is probably not visible anyway.

Comment: "StackExchange appropriates the user's intellectual property (the post)" - How on Earth do we do that? There's still a name attached to it, even if it's just a user### name now. It's a unique Id number recognizing that a past user contributed this content. You're making some very weird claims here.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard Just playing devil's advocate here since this post made me wonder (and I don't know anything about licenses), who is the "you" in the first quote? The author or Stack Exchange? Because that page also says "You must give appropriate credit" and in this context that is Stack Exchange (Stack Overflow). If it is Stack Exchange, then they are not the ones that can revoke the freedoms.

Comment: @animuson But this anonymous user is not the author of my post. Either leave the name of the original author or remove the post.

Comment: @CaveJohnson the "you", as far as I understand, is the one who wants to use the content. The licensor is the author of the post. Again, that's how I see it, and I might be wrong hence just comments.

Comment: You're still on about this (and still angry about your voting ring breakup)? Last time you asked about this (recently deleted), I said: While the question is about a user’s own voluntary profile removal, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386743/1274780) explains what can happen when a profile is deleted (whether voluntarily or forcefully): “Your questions and answers will remain on the site, but will be disassociated and anonymized (the author will be listed as “userXXXXXXXX”) and will not indicate your authorship even if you later return to the site.”

Comment: It's not a copyright violation, no matter how many times you insist it is.

Comment: @Stuck at 1337 I know that this is the case with removing the name, but I personally see removing the name as a problem.

Comment: If a profile gets deleted because they broke the rules, then the profile gets deleted - including the name. Maybe you could argue that’s not the way it should be, but that’s the way that it is. Next time, don’t break the rules.

Comment: In seriousness, flag the answer for a moderator, if you can do that while suspended, and if you ask the right way and without any of the other whinging you’ve done here, they may look into re-parenting your post to you (or at least asking staff to put a meaningful display name).

Comment: @Stuck at 1337 I didn't whinge. During the suspension I can't do anything there, not even flag.

Answer (score 13):

> So it was explained to me that if a user is removed, regardless of the StackExchange [sic] site, the name will also be removed from all of their posts.

Nitpick: Stack Exchange has a space in it. That aside, you are correct. They'll become something like `userXXXXXX` instead (typically).

> Since this procedure is present on all StackExchange sites, it cannot be discussed on any of these sites. I have also read the terms of service several times, but there is nothing there about me giving up all my rights to my posts to StackExchange [sic].

Uh... no. From the ToS:

> You agree that any and all content [...] that you provide to the public Network [...], is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow on a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive basis pursuant to Creative Commons licensing terms (CC BY-SA 4.0), and you grant Stack Overflow the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to access, use, process, copy, distribute, export, display and to commercially exploit such Subscriber Content, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by you [...]

Note: I am not a lawyer, and this is not legal advice.

While I've trimmed that for brevity, it states that, effectively, by posting content on Stack Exchange, you (a) grant a irrevocable right to SE to use it how they want, and (b) you license it under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license*. In other words, SE is absolutely allowed to keep hosting your content after your account is deleted. [Here](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/5663/26361) is a somewhat better explanation, but the gist is that your content is dual-licensed to Stack Exchange.

---

*Some older content is under a previous version of that license, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: The point of contention here seems to be that CC BY-SA requires *attribution*. The content itself is left up because that is indeed part of the terms you agreed to. However, removing the username is likely in breach of the attribution required by the very license that allows SE to keep displaying the content after an account is deleted.

Comment: @VLAZ Sure, but the CC isn't the only license at play here. From what I can tell, it's fine because of the dual licensing. I suppose that could be a problem if disassociated content is used by someone else, via, say, the data dump. Although that’s beyond the scope of the question

Comment: The question doesn't refer to the fact that stackexchange is not allowed to use my content, Creative Commons Licensing, as I know it, I still have to be named as the author of my content.